# How to insert if else ladder in SQL query which is using GROUP BY CLAUSE

Tags: oracle, if-statement, group-by

I am using ORACLE db and I am trying to create SQL query for the following requirement.

Following is my table snapshot:

```
 ID  STATUS
----------
 1     WORKING
 1     QUEUING
 1     SLEEPING
 2     FAILED
 2     SLEEPING
 2     SLEEPING
 3     QUEUING
 3     IDLE
```

Expected output:

```
 1  WORKING
 2  FAILED
 3  QUEUING
```

Status can be either WORKING,QUEUING,FAILED,SLEEPING

I want to insert following conditions in the SQL query, which are listed in the preference order:

- If any of the entry in group contains 'WORKING' I want to set final
  result as 'WORKING' for the group
- if any of the entry is 'FAILED' then result is 'FAILED'
- if any of entry is 'QUEUING' then result is 'QUEUING';
- DEFAULT 'IDLE'.

Comment: I guess you mean you want to use `case when..`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pivot query combined with a subquery should give you what you want:

```
SELECT t.ID,
    CASE WHEN t.Working > 0 THEN 'WORKING'
         WHEN t.Failed > 0  THEN 'FAILED'
         WHEN t.Queuing > 0 THEN 'QUEUING'
    ELSE 'IDLE'
    END AS STATUS
FROM
(
    SELECT ID,
        SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'WORKING' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Working,
        SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'FAILED'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Failed,
        SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'QUEUING' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Queuing
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY ID
) t
```

The reason the outer `CASE` expression correctly represents the preferences is because Oracle always does [short circuit evaluation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43352/does-sql-server-case-statement-evaluate-all-conditions-or-exit-on-first-true-con).  This means that if the query comes across an ID which matches `WORKING`, then the other two checks will not be performed (and similar logic applies for each status).

Comment: Query is not working for ID 1 if there are 2 entries for 'WORKING' and 1 entry for 'QUEUING'. Answer should be WORKING since it has highest preference

Comment: @Vinit89 Thanks for letting me know that there might be more than one status per ID.  I updated my query to account for this and it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

How to do it without `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN STATUS IN ( 'WORKING', 'FAILED', 'QUEUING' )
            THEN STATUS
            ELSE 'IDLE'
            END AS STATUS
FROM   (
  SELECT ID,
         STATUS,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY ID
           ORDER BY CASE STATUS WHEN 'WORKING' THEN 1
                                WHEN 'FAILED'  THEN 2
                                WHEN 'QUEUING' THEN 3
                                ELSE                4 END
        ) AS rn
  FROM  table_name
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```